Evaluate ${d \over da} \left({da \over db}\right)$, where $a$ is a function of $b$?
This is to help a younger sibling with their work. They didn't know how to evaluate the derivative. I want to check and make sure it was correct:

Evaluate ${d \over da} \left({da \over db}\right)$, where $a$ is a function of $b$.

Solution: Set $q = {da \over db}$. Then from the chain rule
$${dq \over db} = {dq \over da} {da \over db} $$
which implies
$$ {dq \over da} = {dq \over db} \div {da \over db} = {d^2a \over db^2} \div {da \over db} $$
Thus we have that
$$ \boxed{{d \over da}{da \over db} = {d^2 a \over db^2 }  \div  {da \over db} }$$

Would this be correct?

It is correct..

Yes, except for the fact that typically the symbol $\div$ is not used outside of gradeschool. Just write a fraction:
$$
\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 a}{\mathrm{d}b^2}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}a}{\mathrm{d}b}}
$$

The divide by symbol is still quite acceptable; although it has been superseded by the dash.

Yes; that is if $a$ is twice differentiable, and $\mathrm d a/\mathrm d b$ is non-zero at the points of interest:
$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d a}{\mathrm d b}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d a}\dfrac{\mathrm d a}{\mathrm d b} &= \dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d b}\dfrac{\mathrm d a}{\mathrm d b}&&\text{chain rule}\\[2ex]\therefore\qquad\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d a}\dfrac{\mathrm d a}{\mathrm d b}&=\left(\dfrac{\mathrm d a}{\mathrm d b}\right)^{-1}\cdotp\dfrac{\mathrm d^2 a}{\mathrm d b~^2}&&\text{inversion}\end{align}$$

Most of us are accustomed to $y=f(x)$ where y is a function of x. Habit and comfort.
Accordingly with
$$ (x,y)\to (b,a) $$
and when primes denote differentiation with respect to $x$ we have
$$ \frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)= \frac{d}{dy}\left(y'\right)= \frac{dy'/dx}{dy/dx}=\frac{y''}{y'}$$
Last step obtained by Chain Rule. Now we can switch the variables back to $(a,b)$ as
$$\frac{a''}{a'}$$
when primes are w.r.t. $b$.
